# How to use a local tomcat version with maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

This may have been asked before (if it is please link me), but when I search I'm finding a bunch of how to run maven on tomcat, how to hook up an IDE to do this (nearly all of them are ide / configuration questions), how to use maven plugin in tomcat, etc related questions.

I know I can use an IDE like intellij or eclipse to create a web app project with maven, and tomcat and they will just run because of the settings configurations. I'm playing around and trying to see how to do it manually (hopefully to learn something).

Right now I have a running tomcat project. Essentially I downloaded tomcat 8 from http://tomcat.apache.org/. I then pulled the example files, and have it running my own files.

I want to wrap this in maven.

I created a typical maven project (example):

```
.
|____WebApp
| |____pom.xml
| |____src
| | |____main
| | | |____resources
| | | |____webapp
| | | | |____index.jsp
| | | | |____WEB-INF
| | | | | |____web.xml
```

Where do I put my tomcat file? 
in webApp?

To run tomcat I am using

```
bin/catalina.sh run
```

From my tomcat file. Can I run it from my pom, or would I need to create a java file to call it somehow?

If I do it in Intellij (through the automated creation process) it all runs. But I can't figure out how each file is linked other than through .idea related means. There is no tomcat file for example. No server.xml that I can see although it is referenced in the pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tomcat-run</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <path>foo</path>
                                <!-- optional, needed only if you want to use a preconfigured server.xml file -->
                                <serverXml>src/main/tomcatconf/server.xml</serverXml>
                                <!-- optional values which can be configurable -->
                                <attachArtifactClassifier>default value is exec-war but you can customize</attachArtifactClassifier>
                                <attachArtifactClassifierType>default value is jar</attachArtifactClassifierType>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

But in this case it's a plugin which appears to be slightly different than I'm doing (correct me if that's wrong, I'm new to maven / tomcat)

My interpretation of what is going on in intellij is that the maven project is being run on tomcat. Where as I want to use maven to run my tomcat project that has its own files. (if you can explain this better or correct me here, I would be very appreciative) They both reference in some way the server.xml file.

**------
EDIT
Ok so I reread: mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat**

I believe that running my tomcat catalina.sh in my tomcat file (as downloaded from apache example) will allow me to keep my paths. The problem I am struggling with is the following:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
            <server>TomcatServer</server>
            <path>/mkyongWebApp</path>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The way that the example uses tomcat is by using it as a plugin. This means that it will never read my tomcat file. How do I get it to run my local tomcat file.

Comment: Try to read http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/

Comment: @rpc1 Hey, thanks for commenting. I read that actually. Perhaps I misunderstood. But my understanding was that it runs a maven war on tomcat. I'm not trying to run a maven project on tomcat. I'm trying to use maven to run my tomcat project. If you look at the tomcat basic download you will see it launches a web page. I do not in this case want to over ride that web page. I know thats a weird request but its just exercise I wanted to try.

Comment: @rpc1 hmm maybe you're right. I read through the page again. I didn't want something like /mkyoungWebApp but it appears from his example the original tomcat directories are not overwritten. Is this true? Can you confirm? If I didn't want any maven created directories can I just omit path?

Comment: @rpc1 also do you happen to know a link to documentation about how conflicts are resolved? ex what if I specify a maven path that conflicts with tomcats?

Comment: I think, if application exists you'll have an error: 
 [INFO] Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Application already exists at path /mywebapp

Comment: @rpc1 ok so conflicts will occur on paths. But otherwise if I run tomcat server.xml via maven all paths that are unset by maven will continue to provide the same experience as they did when run from the terminal. Interesting! Thank you. (If you post this as an answer I will accept it if you want) ... Also wait I re-read the example again, the example uses a plugin, how do I reference my actual file?

Comment: Do you wants that maven auto undeploy existing project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80626/discussion-between-tai-hirabayashi-and-rpc1).

Comment: Chat is blocked by firewall on my job

Comment: Maven plugin has parameters https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

Comment: oh darn, ok. I think the problem still exists.
<plugin> 
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId> 
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>2.2</version> 
<configuration> 
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url> 
<server>TomcatServer</server> 
<path>/mkyongWebApp</path> 
</configuration> 
</plugin>
is how it's connected in the exmple
I have an actual tomcat downloaded file

Comment: Property  maven.tomcat.update.  undeploy existing project before deploy

Comment: @rpc1 sorry still confused. What does "Property maven.tomcat.update. undeploy existing project before deploy" mean? wait one sec reading your earlier message link

Comment: it connetcts using request  http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FmkyongWebApp&update=true

Comment: user/passowrds declares in settings.xml

Comment: maven.tomcat.update. it means you don't get error if project exists in tomcat.... tomcat removes existing project and puts new project

Comment: @rpc1 sorry can you give an example. Let's say we have a tomcat file -> tomcat-> bin -> catalina.sh, and a maven project. Where does maven.tomcat.update.undeploy go? What would the file structure look like?

Comment: I'm sorry but my working day starts ) I have to do my job! have a nice day

Comment: @rpc1 ok thanks for the help, good luck with work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/executable-war-jar.html

Ex you set the serverXml to point to your local tomcat installation.

```
<project>
  ...
  <packaging>war or pom</packaging>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <path>foo</path>
              <!-- optional, needed only if you want to use a preconfigured server.xml file -->
              <serverXml>src/main/tomcatconf/server.xml</serverXml>
              <!-- optional values which can be configurable -->
              <attachArtifactClassifier>default value is exec-war but you can customize</attachArtifactClassifier>
              <attachArtifactClassifierType>default value is jar</attachArtifactClassifierType>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```